# method_help en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola a todo necesito hacer un help_method que me entregue los
datos de la tabla contact, ahora tengo esto en un archivo partial del layout que es la cabecera (head) de la web, que se carga según el rol del contacto y el tipo de user (que si es administrador del sitio o cliente del mismo), funciona perfectamente.

codigo:

```
<div class="headerSS">
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-lewagon" >
    <div class = "container-fluid">
      <div class= "photo">
        <% Client.find(user_id: current_user.id) do |user|%>
          <%= image_tag user.logo, class:"imagen" %>  
        <%end%>
      </div>

      <button class="navbar-toggler text-white" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%id = clientID(current_user.id).id%>
            <% idcontact = HistContact.last%>
            <% contactID = Contact.find_by(id: idcontact.contact_id)%>
            <% if contactID.roles == "Administrador" %>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to "Inicio", clients_home_path(), class: "nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to "Usuarios", client_contacts_path(id), class: "nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to "Reservas ",  client_reservations_path(id), class: "nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to "Habitacion", client_rooms_path(id), class: "nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown lastDrop">
                <%= link_to "Dinero", "#", class: "avatar dropdown-toggle nav-link text-white", id: "navbarDropdown", data: { bs_toggle: "dropdown" }, 'aria-haspopup': true, 'aria-expanded': false %>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <%= link_to "Cuenta Banco", client_client_currentaccounts_path(id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                  <%#= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %>
                </div>  
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown lastDrop">
                <%= link_to "Politicas", "#", class: "avatar dropdown-toggle nav-link text-white", id: "navbarDropdown", data: { bs_toggle: "dropdown" }, 'aria-haspopup': true, 'aria-expanded': false %>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <%= link_to "Edad", client_age_policies_path(id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                  <%= link_to "Devolucion", client_refund_policies_path(id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                  <%= link_to "Cancelacion", client_cancel_policies_path(id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                  <%= link_to "Cambio", client_change_policies_path(id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                  <%#= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %>
                </div>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown lastDrop">
                <%= link_to "Historial", "#", class: "avatar dropdown-toggle nav-link text-white", id: "navbarDropdown", data: { bs_toggle: "dropdown" }, 'aria-haspopup': true, 'aria-expanded': false %>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <%= link_to "Empresa", hist_user_index_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
                  <%= link_to "Funcionario", hist_contact_index_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: " nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
            <% else %>
               <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to "Inicio", clients_home_path(), class: "nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to "Reservas ",  client_reservations_path(id), class: "nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to "Habitacion", client_rooms_path(id), class: "nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
                <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: " nav-link text-white" %>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          
          <% else %>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, class: "nav-link" %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class= "col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-end clientName">
          <%Client.find(user_id: current_user.id) do |c| %>
          <%= c.name%>
        <%end%>
      </div>
      <div class= "col-sm-6 col-md-6 rigth-end clientUserClient" >
        <!--<% Contact.find(user_id: current_user.id) do |ct|%>-->
          <%= contactID.name%>
        <%end%>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Tengo entendido que toda la lógica tiene que ir en los controladores.

hablo de estas lineas

```
 <%id = clientID(current_user.id).id%>
            <% idcontact = HistContact.last%>
            <% contactID = Contact.find_by(id: idcontact.contact_id)%>
            <% if contactID.roles == "Administrador" %>
```

Esta función es para determinar el rol y el id de cliente

La pregunta es como puedo hacerlo desde un controlador, ya que esto es un head dentro del layout, he pensado en hacer un helper_method, pero no me resulta.

Me pueden explicar como hacer el helper_method

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La lógica que describes más que en un helper, se me hace algo que debería estar en el modelo del contacto, ya que podrías llegar a necesitarlo a nivel de controlador de igual forma.

```
class Contact
  # ...

  def admin?
    roles == "Administrador"
  end

  def self.last_hist_contact
    # comento esto, porque en el código que destacaste no se hace uso de una
    # variable `id`, sino mas bien se usa en la vista
    # id = clientID(id).id

    # Aparte aquí se me hace que estas dos líneas podrían hacerse
    # en una única query a la BD, pero no has compartido más código del
    # necesario para inferir eso, así que lo dejo tal cual
    idcontact = HistContact.last
    Contact.find_by(id: idcontact.contact_id)
  end
end
```

luego, crea un helper como:

```
def last_contact
  @last_contact ||= Contact.last_hist_contact
end
```

y finalmente en tu vista

```
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <% id = clientID(current_user.id).id%>
        <% if last_contact.admin? %>
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo mañana en la mañana

Comment: Me funciona perfectamente, consulta Alter, por que es mejor ocupar el Model en vez del Controlador.

Comment: Es una de las convenciones de Rails donde sugieren que ese tipo de lógica debería ir en el modelo, ya que está estrictamente relacionada con ese modelo en particular, aparte te permite poder testear de mejor maera tu lógica. Igual, como todo en la vida, tampoco está escrito en piedra y habrán casos donde será mejor dejar cierta lógica a nivel de controlador. Puedes googlear "fat model skinny controller" para mas info.

Comment: Gracias entendí